# How to display image from model in Django

Tags: python, django, image, upload

To be clear, I have tried researching this on my own but since I'm still very new to Django I am unable to understand the solutions here. I also have read the documentation and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I cannot get the images located in the "ad_pictures" directory to display in the HTML.

Here's my code:

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py (project)

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^classifieds/', include('classifieds.urls')),

 ] +static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_ROOT=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

urls.py (classifieds app)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'classifieds'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/', views.create, name='create'),
    url(r'^latestads/', views.latestads, name='latestads'),
]
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='ad_pictures', default='')
```

latestads.html

```
            {% for post in posts.all %}
            <div class="advertisements">
              <div class="a-title">
                <h3><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="a-image">
                <a href=""><img src="{{ post.picture.url }}"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="a-content">
                <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="a-date">
                <p>{{ post.pub_date }} by {{ post.author }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="{{ post.image.url }}">
            {% endfor %}
```

Picture of directory structure:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlnD2.png)

Html output:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ4A3.png)

I'm sure part of the problem is the "post.picture.url" in the HTML. 
Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When you inspect the web page what is the current image url django try to render?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/9a995fa5330d59d465519338bdbe0bc4.png

Comment: Which version of django you are using?

Comment: I'm using 1.11.10

Comment: @Awpulance does that media URL loading on browser

Comment: Ok I deleted the ad_pictures directory and this time just used "media" as the folder my images will go to, and I took out the "upload_to=" argument in an attempt to simplify things and unfortunately it's still rendering a broken image.

Comment: @AfsalSalim Im not sure what you mean

Comment: @Awpulance please inspect the webpage and open the media url on another tab, please check whether images is loading

Comment: Ok the media url is "/media/dKAiVtd.jpg" so am I supposed to just add that to 127.0.0.1:8000? If so i get the following: `serve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'document_ROOT'`

Comment: @Awpulance i got the issue. I will post the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^classifieds/', include('classifieds.urls')),

 ] +static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

please change document_ROOT to document_root

Comment: nice to hear that :D @Awpulance could you please upload vote :D